# How to Show a Calender in android by clicking a simple button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator

could any one help me how to Show a Calender in android by clicking a simple button

I have a button in andriod ,if we click on a buttton the user should be able to select date from calender

Comment: U mean a date picker or Calendar application ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DatePickerDialog for this i am posting a sample code for you

```
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999; 
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;

date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel(val);
            }
        };


        depart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                val = 1;
            }
        });


        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        final Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            DatePickerDialog _date = new DatePickerDialog(this, date,
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    if (year - now.get(Calendar.YEAR) > 1) {
                        view.updateDate(year - 1,
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    }
                    if (year - now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 1
                            && monthOfYear > now.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
                        view.updateDate(year, myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    }
                    if (year - now.get(Calendar.YEAR) == 1
                            && monthOfYear == now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                            && dayOfMonth > now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                        view.updateDate(year, myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    }
                    if (year < now.get(Calendar.YEAR))

                        view.updateDate(myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    if (monthOfYear < now.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                            && year == now.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                        view.updateDate(myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                    if (dayOfMonth < now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                            && year == now.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                            && monthOfYear == now.get(Calendar.MONTH))
                        view.updateDate(myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                }
            };
            return _date;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

To set the Date :

```
private void updateLabel(int val) {
        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yy"; // In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        Log.d("Date value ", "===" + sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        depart.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To open calendar from button click event add this code to onClick method:

```
 Intent i = new Intent();

//Froyo or greater (mind you I just tested this on CM7 and the less than froyo one worked so it depends on the phone...)
cn = new ComponentName("com.google.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

//less than Froyo
cn = new ComponentName("com.android.calendar", "com.android.calendar.LaunchActivity");

i.setComponent(cn);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a date picker then you can check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) out.

Or you can use [this](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker) library as latest version of date picker.